# NameError: uninitialized constant Class::Class in a rake-task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake-task

I'm trying to make a rake-task in a such way:

```
require 'open-uri'

namespace :news_parser do
  desc 'Parsing news from 6 news sites'
  task :parse_news do
    load 'lib/news_parser.rb'
    ProcherkParser.new.save_novelties
    VikkaParser.new.save_novelties
    InfomistParser.new.save_novelties
    ZmiParser.new.save_novelties
    VycherpnoParser.new.save_novelties
    ProvceParser.new.save_novelties
  end
end
```

In my `lib/news_parser.rb` I have classes and instance methods, which perfectly work in a rails console, by doing the following:

```
load 'lib/news_parser.rb'
ProcherkParser.new.save_novelties
```

It saves to my db all the information I need. But how can I do it in a rake-task? Any help would be appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does it work when you replace

```
task :parse_news do
```

with

```
task :parse_news => :environment do
```

?

It will load your Rails environment before your task, and your code should work just like in the rails console.

Also, you could DRY your code a bit :

```
require 'open-uri'

namespace :news_parser do
  desc 'Parsing news from 6 news sites'
  task :parse_news => :environment do
    load 'lib/news_parser.rb'
    [ProcherkParser, VikkaParser, InfomistParser, ZmiParser, VycherpnoParser, ProvceParser].each do |parser_klass|
      parser_klass.new.save_novelties
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am using in my app

```
namespace :raw_logs do
  desc 'Download - Decrypt - Save raw logs'
  task process: :environment do
   LogItem.create(org_id: 12)
  end
end
```

My rake task is rake `raw_logs:process`